# Checkbox to show delayed flags in the mod flag queue

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, flags, moderator-tools

Some flags, like NAA and VLQ flags, are by default delayed by half an hour (?) before entering the mod flag queue. On bigger sites, this is theoretically enough time to allow the content to be handled in the site's review queue.

On smaller sites, though, things are very rarely completely handled by review, and the flags end up getting shown to moderators anyway. Just with a time delay.

If I, as a moderator, am around, I'd really like to be able to handle everything from one spot. Sure, I could go through the low-quality-posts review queue if I wanted to, but it's much harder to triage what needs handled first (low hanging fruit first, anyone?) from review. **It's easier to handle flags from the flag queue**.

So, can we have a checkbox in the sidebar for this?

[image]

It would do what it says on the tin, show all the active flags on the site.

Thoughts?

Comment: Might it not be better in such cases to delay *somewhat longer* (say, up to two hours, off the top of my head) to give small sites time to spin through their community moderation? Seeing a lot of reviews end with `n-1` reviewers and then a mod finishing it is just sad.

Comment: @NathanTuggy On a decent chunk of sites, you're going to have to extend it to >12 hours to get enough people with delete votes to see it. That's not practical.

Comment: In that case, I suppose having both would be helpful; for the slow but sure sites, delaying more is the way to go, and for the really tiny, just let everything in immediately.

Comment: [You sure like checkboxes](http://meta.stackexchange.com/search?q=user%3A215468+checkbox)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It looks like this may have been implemented.   I'm seeing this on Pro Webmasters where I am a moderator:

> ignore time filter (some flags are not shown immediately by default)

[image]

Here is another meta question where somebody is asking about what it is:  [“Ignore time filter” in moderator flag view](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/292878/ignore-time-filter-in-moderator-flag-view).   Here is another thread where somebody already wants a change to it: [Make it possible to have new “ignore time filter” option checked by default](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/292879/make-it-possible-to-have-new-ignore-time-filter-option-checked-by-default)

Comment: Wow, blast from the past. Completely forgot I'd asked this, but several iterations later and it's implemented. Thanks!

Comment: Unfortunately the tickbox appears to be forgetful and not retain its state.