# "Ignore time filter" in moderator flag view

Tags: support, flags, moderator-tools

I noticed this in the moderator dashboard today:

> [image: Ignore time filter option]

What sort of wizardry is this? I did a [search](https://meta.stackexchange.com/search?q=time+filter+flag) on meta for this feature, didn't find anything. What's being filtered and why are we doing that?

Comment: It is basically for NAA flags. The NAA flags are available on the moderator queue only after 1 hr. If you select that, it will appear immediately.

Comment: related: https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/247658/133299 and [Checkbox to show delayed flags in the mod flag queue](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/267084/133299)

Comment: @BhargavRao I think it's 15 minutes on smaller sites.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

The community gets a head start on Not An Answer and Very Low Quality flags; those flags send a post to the Low-Quality Posts review queue.  On large, active sites, the community handles these quickly and they require no moderator action.  Therefore, there is a time delay before those flags appear on the moderators' flags page, in hopes that we can avoid bothering mods with them at all.

Checking that box means "yeah, but I'm not that patient and I want to see them now -- gimme!".