# Make it possible to have new "ignore time filter" option checked by default

Tags: feature-request, flags, moderator-tools

This new feature is pretty nifty!

As the moderator of a small site with few flags, it'd be really cool if it were possible to have a setting that allowed me to keep the box ticked by default rather than unchecked.

I know that mods on bigger sites are probably happy to let these flags age in to visibility but when you have a site with few users who have access to the reviews, it'd be nice to see them sooner.

I grant that clicking the box isn't hugely troublesome so this wouldn't necessarily be high priority.

---

Possible options:

- Configurable by moderator (there's a button that, if checked, keeps the setting until unchecked)
- Saves state for the duration of the use of the moderator panel.
- Configurable by site as decided by the moderators or the flag volume.
- Defaults to checked if there are fewer than X flags on the flag page (excluding the ones made visible when checking the box)

Comment: Let it just save the state. Also, if you set it once, then when you navigate to the other mod pages, that particular option is always set. When you re-navigate from another page, it is unchecked. (On SO, there are usually around 50~ extra flags which we'd need to handle if the "ignore time filter" was set by default.)

Comment: It would *certainly* be improved by saving the state if you stay within the confines of the mod panel... but your issue with the number of flags on SO is exactly why I'm requesting there be a way to pick... or maybe it can be configured by site with lower-volume flag sites having it default to visible? Or perhaps it defaults to visible when the total number of flags is less than 15? It doesn't have to be settable by mod necessarily, but it would be nice if it was a bit smarter.

Comment: Gotcha, the states are saved (by appending ?filtered=false to the URLs) when you are in the flags tab. But true, having an option is a better idea. Simpler solution would be to create an userscript, that adds `?filtered=false` to the end of the queues. (where's Undo when we need him).

Comment: @Bhargav He's been undone.

Comment: The state of this box should not only be saved, it should then be applied across the entire site.