# Waffle bar appears on page with very recent VLQ flag but shows no content

Tags: bug, flags, moderator-tools, waffle-bar

When I open the Q&A page for an answer with a very recent (less than 15 minutes old) Very Low Quality flag, the 'waffle bar' (a moderator tool for handling flags) shows, but there's no content:

[image]

This is how it *should* look like, and looks like after waiting 15 minutes:

[image]

I've just seen a new (less than 15 minutes old) NAA flag, cast by a user, on Ask Different and in that case the waffle bar isn't shown at all. Another VLQ flag on ELL.SE, this time cast by a user (the previous one was an automatic flag by the system), and the 'empty' waffle bar is shown again. It looks like it's limited to VLQ flags.

This happens both in Safari (where I have no userscripts running) and Firefox on macOS Catalina. There's nothing suspicious in the browser console or the network requests. The post itself isn't too suspicious either, it's just a link to Quora. I'll comment and if the author doesn't improve it, I'll delete it after the bug is analyzed.

Comment: I think it's tied to the delay in showing NAA/VLQ flags to mods, if it's still in the delay period you get the empty waffle bar. (I get them a lot after flagging NAA on IPS)

Comment: @Tinkeringbell that's a plausible theory, I'll keep the dashboards open, waiting for new flags. In that case, wouldn't it be better to not show the bar at all?

Comment: I like the empty bar: It helps dismiss VLQ flags on off-topic posts as well (they shouldn't [be flagged as such](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/328577/369802)). I'm going to say we keep it.

Comment: @Tinkeringbell wouldn't you rather have it shown like the second screenshot? Then it's a lot easier to decline.

Comment: That would work too, and perhaps it's even already possible. I'm not sure what effect ignoring the time filter could have on this empty bar, for example. But that checkbox isn't [checked by default](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/292879/369802), the empty waffle bar does show up by default. I think having them show up like the second one on default is going to give problems for the people that use the waffle bar to navigate the flag queue?

Comment: I'm not sure this is a bug, exactly. It may be [tag:status-bydesign], as it's *the* indicator there's an active flag on the page which *could be* addressed by the moderator in the flag dashboard, if the moderator wants to open the flag dashboard with the time filter disabled. It certainly could be much better. For example, it could/should allow the moderator to expand the waffle bar to show the pending, time-filtered flag(s), rather than *just* being blank.

Comment: @Makyen given the workload you have on SO, I can imagine that; but in that case, I'd rather have the waffle bar disappear entirely. In the current situation, I know *something* is going on, and in less ideal circumstances, I have to check the flag history of half a dozen posts to see *what*.

Comment: I'm getting this on a question flagged by a user as VLQ, but it says "close this dialog", maybe because I'm on mobile Chrome.  (I think you can see it in the list of all flags, maybe by choosing "ignore time filter".)